# How to get input value using val() with js and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have been trying to take values of 4 inputs that are in a table and get the sum of the numbers on the input with a for loop but i keep getting 0 (the sum that i have defined)

Debugged everything and I am pretty sure the problem is in the "var x"- it just won't get any information from the inputs.

```js
$(function () {

 $("#inventoryForm").submit(function (event) {
  var table = $("table")
        var error = false;
  event.preventDefault();
          $(".inventoryInput").each(function(){
            if($(this).val() < 0) {

                error = true; //Indicate there was an error
                $("#inventoryError").slideDown().text("Positive numbers only");
                return false; //This stops the iteration
            }

        });

        //Stop processing if there was an error
        if (error) return;
        if (!error) {
          $("#inventoryError").hide(); 
        }
  $("#inventorySubmit").hide();
  $("#inventoryChange").show();
  $("#withdraw").show();
  $(".inventoryInput").attr('disabled','disabled');
  var sum = 0;
    var money = table.find("td:nth-child(2)");
  for (var i = 0; i<money.length; i++) {
    var x = money.eq(i).val();
   sum += x;
   $("#totalMoney").text(sum);
  }
  console.log(money);
  
 });

 $("#inventoryChange").click(function () {
  $("#inventorySubmit").show();
  $("#inventoryChange").hide();
  $("#withdraw").hide();
  $(".inventoryInput").removeAttr('disabled');
 });


});
```

```css
.hidden {
 display: none;
}
.error {
    display: none;
    color: red;
    border: dotted 3px yellow;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>ATM</title>
<body>
    <header>
         <h1>Litman - Steklov ATMs</h1>

    </header>
    <section id="inventory">
        <form id="inventoryForm">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Bill</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>20</td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="inventoryInput" class="inventoryInput" type="number">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>50</td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="inventoryInput2" class="inventoryInput" type="number">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>100</td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="inventoryInput3" class="inventoryInput" type="number">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>200</td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="inventoryInput4" class="inventoryInput" type="number">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <p id="inventoryError" class="error hidden">Validation errors will be here</p>
            <p>Total Money: <span id="totalMoney"></span> 
            </p>
            <button id="inventorySubmit" type="submit">Finish</button>
            <button id="inventoryChange" type="button" class="hidden">Change</button>
        </form>
    </section>
    <section id="withdraw" class="hidden">
        <form>
            <div>Withdraw:
                <input type="number">
            </div>
            <p class="error hidden">Validation errors will be here</p>
            <button type="submit">Process</button>
        </form>
    </section>
    <section id="result" class="hidden">
        <div>You Got:</div>
        <button type="button">Finish</button>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You don't mean `java`. And if you want to make sure where the problem is, debug. Log something inside the loop.

Comment: Please edit your question and show your HTML

Comment: @rnevius you can see my HTML on my fiddle above.

Comment: @keyser , I was trying to log "x" and I got nothing- so somehow I don't get any value from the input.

Comment: @ronilitman Then you have an obvious follow-up: log the parts that make up `x`. I'm not saying this will solve your problem but it will give you more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is indeed with

```
var x = money.eq(i).val();
```

`money` is an array of `tds`. So `money.eq(i)` is a td. What you want to get to is the actual `input`. So the solution is

```
var x = money.eq(i).find('input').val();
```

---

To elaborate on your further commend. If you fill in all 4 inputs using

```
var x = parseInt(money.eq(i).find('input').val());
```

it will sum them as expected. It will throw `NaN` when one of the inputs is empty because `parseInt('')` returns `NaN`, so you should check if the input actually has a value or not..

```
var input = money.eq(i).find('input').val();
var x = input ? parseInt(input) : 0
```

---

To further explain my code.

```
var input = money.eq(i).find('input').val();
```

This gets the value of the actual input, whatever that value may be.

```
var x = input ? parseInt(input) : 0
```

This checks whether the value of the input is empty or not. If it is empty then `x=0` otherwise `x=parseInt(input)`. So if the input is not empty, the value if being parsed to an `int` and assigned to `x`.

```
sum += x
```

x is being added to the final sum.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. For now, I just getting the numbers like strings. for exmaple- if I entered "2" on the first input and "1" on the second the result will be "021". Tried to correct it with parseInt but got "NaN" as a result. Do you know how can I fix it? My input is defined of a "number" type.

Comment: Edited my answer to include fix for that.

Comment: It worked. I just don't get it- If I do sum += x but I defined my input values with "var input", how does it know to relate it?

Comment: Further edited my answer and explained each line of code

Comment: Glad to help, my friend

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78633/discussion-between-roni-litman-and-dan-moldovan).